# Encoding PNG image with specific filter type using Imagemagick

Tags: image, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

Just trying to re-encode a PNG file with a specific filtering method using image magick command line tool ('convert' tool to be specific).

As per [this page](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/formats/) , we can set the quality parameter using two decimal figures , first figure being the  zlib compression level used when 1-9 is used and the second figure indicates filter method to use (which is used before the compression)

But with the above option used always filter type '0' (i.e no filter) is used when encoding , even when I specify filter type other than '0'.

eg  with below command

```
convert -quality 11 in.png out.png
```

I should get output image with zlib compression level 1 (which I am not bothered about) and filter type '1' ('sub' type of filtering).

But the out image is always with filter type '0' , even if I change quality level to 11 , 12 ..15 etc (corresponding to filters '1' , '2' ...'5' etc).

Also tried with controls as per [this page](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/formats/#png_write) , but results are same.

Helps are appreciated!

Comment: This is so specialized, it might be better to ask through their dedicated support channels

Comment: Hmm , I will try to use that channel as well.Thanks!

Comment: Does the order make a difference? `convert input.png -quality 11 output.png`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "filter method" in the IHDR chunk of any PNG file is always 0.
What ImageMagick/GraphicsMagick's "quality" digit controls is the
filter type used in each scanline.  So "-quality 11" will produce
a PNG file that has filter_method=0 in IHDR, and "filter_type=1" as
the first byte of each row.

If you have "pngtest" that comes with libpng, you can find out which
filter types are used:

```
pngtest -m out.png
```

yields for example

```
PASS (3396 zero samples)
Filter 1 was used 24 times
Filter 2 was used 478 times
Filter 3 was used 2 times
Filter 4 was used 241 times
libpng passes test
```

EDIT: There does seem to have been a fleeting problem with ImageMagick. Under version 7.0.2-9, "-quality 11"
is producing an image with all rows having filter_type 0 as you noted.
"-quality 15" does work properly, with all four filter_types being present.
GraphicsMagick, ImageMagick-7.0.3-0, and ImageMagick-6.9.5-9 are working properly.

Comment: First part of your answer covered my doubt. Was confused between method and type. I have a query about the second part;if we specify type as 5 shouldn't be all scan lines filtered with type 5?

Comment: There is no filter type 5.  That is a flag that asks libpng to choose a filter type among 0-4 for each scanline based on a heuristic that attempts to get the best compression.